# Can't reset CSS Appearance Property

Tags: html, css, html-select

A site I'm working on has remove the drop down arrow from  boxes with:

```
select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

I need to add it back in, but nothing I've tried has worked so far

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
select.diff {
  /* Aswell as normal, I have also tried revert & unset */
  -webkit-appearance: normal;
  -moz-appearance: normal;
  appearance: normal;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Trains</option>
  <option>Planes</option>
  <option>Automobiles</option>
</select>
<select class="diff">
  <option>Oranges</option>
  <option>Pears</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Resetting it isn't an option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) (check out the formal syntax), probably because it's not part of an actual standard.

Comment: Just a reference for anyone coming across this post but maybe looking for a different element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to set as `menulist`

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
select.diff {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  -moz-appearance: menulist;
  appearance: menulist;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Trains</option>
  <option>Planes</option>
  <option>Automobiles</option>
</select>
<select class="diff">
  <option>Oranges</option>
  <option>Pears</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
</select>
```

Check `appearance` options [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)

Comment: thanks.  Do you know what the other valuer to the appearance property are?  Or somewhere I can look them up

Answer (score 2):

you may use the `:not()` pseudo class to filter `select` to witch apply that rule:

```css
select:not([class]) {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Trains</option>
  <option>Planes</option>
  <option>Automobiles</option>
</select>
<select class="diff">
  <option>Oranges</option>
  <option>Pears</option>
  <option>Apple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also You need to know that there is syntax error ("none").
This is the list of possible options for appearance:
appearance: normal|icon|window|button|menu|field

You can check it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp).